# Implementing Graphql Federation in Spring Cloud Gateway (JAVA) connecting with NodeJS/TS microservices

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, graphql, api-gateway, federation

I am facing issues in setting up Graphql Federation in SpringCloud Gateway.

I have created a Spring Cloud Server and a Eureka Client Server which connects to a Node Typescript microservice.

For Eureka Client in Nodejs, I have used `eureka-js-client` package, which enables the connection from Typescript Service to Eureka.

For enabling Federation in Springboot, I am using the following dependency.

```
`<dependency>
<groupId>com.apollographql.federation</groupId>
<artifactId>federation-graphql-java-support</artifactId>
<version>${federation-graphql-java-support.version}</version>
</dependency>`
```

from [https://github.com/apollographql/federation-jvm]

How do I make the NodeJS graphql Schema accessible to Spring cloud. Is there any other solution to create apollo layer in Spring cloud that creates a supergraph using all the subgraphs from the connected microservices(node).

I tried implementing federation-jvm package in Spring cloud but it fails to acknowledge the `/graphql` and schemas from different node services.

ideally, it should collate all the graphql schemas from all services and create a supergraph which is accessible through API gateway.